# How Do I change Markup of a link in Wordpress

Tags: jquery, css

first off, I am sorry if this question has been asked before, don't seem to get it.

I would like to change the markup of link in Wordpress to something like this

```
<a href="#" class="s1  s1--top" data-hint="tooltip here">Just Words.</a>
```

Where the href would have two extra classes, and I would be able to add words to the data hint dynamically (through the text editor). - It's a tooltip

I have enqueued the stylesheet of the CSS, my main challenge is how to append those extra classes to the a tag, thanks.

I don't mind if someone can help me with JQuery, and lastly, how do I make the tooltip show up.

Comment: Where is the link coming from? Is it generated by a theme or a plugin?

Comment: Yh I think, it's basically any link within my post or pages. E.g If I add a link within my post, the class should automatically append to the a tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Create a `js` folder, at the same level as `style.css` and inside it Create a `main.js` file.
For the tooltip, use [jQuery UI Tooltips](https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) included in WordPress.
You have to call it inside your `functions.php` file like this :

```
/**
 * Enqueue jQuery UI Tooltips.
 */
function my_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-tooltip' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_theme_file_uri( '/js/main.js' ), array( 'jquery' ), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/js/main.js' ) ), true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

As you can see, we have also enqueue the `main.js` file ;-)
Now, open your `main.js` file and add the following :

```
(function ($) {

    $( 'a[href="#"]' ).addClass( 's1  s1--top' );
    $( '.s1' ).tooltip();
    /* OR $( '.s1--top' ).tooltip(); */
    /* OR $( '.s1.s1--top' ).tooltip(); */
    /* OR $( 'a[href="#"]' ).tooltip(); */
    /* OR $( 'a[href="#"].s1' ).tooltip(); */
    /* OR $( 'a[href="#"].s1--top' ).tooltip(); */
    /* OR $( 'a[href="#"].s1.s1--top' ).tooltip(); */

})(jQuery);
```

**FOR THIS TO WORK, YOU SHOULD CHANGE `data-hint` to `title`** like so :
`<a href="#" title="tooltip here">Just Words.</a>`
Classes will be added by `jQuery` and the format will became :
`<a href="#" class="s1  s1--top" title="tooltip here">Just Words.</a>`

**-----EDIT-----**
For the script that you are using, you just need to enqueue the `hint.css`.
Put the file in a `css` folder at the same level as `style.css` and in your `functions.php` add:

```
/**
 * Enqueue HINT.CSS
 */
function hint_css() {

    wp_enqueue_style( 'hint', get_theme_file_uri( '/css/hint.css' ), array(), filemtime( get_theme_file_path( '/css/hint.css' ) ) );

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hint_css' );
```

Now, I think that you know how to make it work as you want ;-)

**IMPORTANT NOTE**
Remember to create a [child theme](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/) for all your modifications or they will be removed on the next update of the theme that you are using (unless you are developing a theme).

SYA :)

Comment: Thanks this looks promising, I have a Js folder already, and I have a specific folder for the CSS called customcss

Comment: If you already have a `js` folder use it directly don't create a new one. If you have any other question regarding this don't hesitate :) don't forget to tell me if it worked for you :) **EDIT** - no need for `CSS` now :)

Comment: It works, thanks but the problem I have is that the tooltip - data-hint, has is own styles, this is what I am trying to implement https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Cool-Tooltips-with-Pure-CSS-Hint.css/

Comment: Happy that it worked for you. I'll edit my answer for the script :) don't forget to bump up my answer after it works :)

Comment: My reputation is low for that, I'll bump it up as soon as I am reputable

Comment: No problem at all, you are most welcome :) See the EDIT part

Comment: Oh my God, it worked like charm, Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple just use the below jQuery code:

```
$("a").addClass("s1");
$("a").addClass("s1--top");
```